# Shiny permissions to read/write tempfiles

Tags: r, linux, shiny, permissions

I have a Shiny App that is locally running without errors. The app involves creating a tempfile for rendering a PDF and then downloading it. When deployed, the server disconnects when rendering the PDF. I am almost certain the problem lies in user permissions in my linux server where the shiny app is hosted.

I have tried `sudo chown -R tvc:shiny-apps .` and `sudo chmod g+w` and `sudo chmod g+s`within the app folder but no permissions changed. I am also not sure if I have to change permissions in the app folder, or if I have to change permissions in the temp folder.

Here is a sample of the code using tempfiles in the shiny `server`:

```
tmp_file <- paste0(tempfile(), ".pdf") #Creating the temp where the .pdf is going to be stored

      render(caminho_rmd, 
             output_file = tmp_file,
             params = params, 
             envir = new.env())

      report$filepath <- tmp_file #Assigning in the temp file where the .pdf is located to the reactive file created above


      })
```

Here are user permissions for the files in the shiny app folder:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 "user" "group" app.R (this is the shiny app)
```

I am confident the problem lies in the directory permissions, but I am not sure if I have to change permissions in the app folder, or if I have to change permissions in the temp folder.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I think `chown` changes the owner, and `chmod` changes file permissions. Have you only tried `chown`?

Comment: Maybe you have to set `intermediates_dir = tempdir()` in the `render` function.

Comment: @cory yes, I have also tried ```chmod g+w``` and ```chmod g+s```, but again permissions remain ```-rw-r--r--```.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I am not sure I understood your suggestion. tempfile() already creates a tempdir(), doesn't it?

Comment: By default, `intermediates_dir` is the folder of the input file. `render` tries to write some intermediate files in this folder. I already encountered this problem and I found that `intermediates_dir` was guilty.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent is the following code what you mean by using intermediate_dir?

`intermediates_dir = tempdir()`
`tmp_file <- paste0(tempfile(tmpdir = intermediates_dir), ".pdf") #Creating the temp where the .pdf is going to be stored`
`render(caminho_rmd, 
             output_file = tmp_file,
             params = params, 
             envir = new.env())`

Comment: No. I mean `render(caminho_rmd, output_file = tmp_file, params = params, envir = new.env(), intermediates_dir = tempdir())`.

Comment: Oh, ok. I tried it, but the shiny app crashes the same. Still works fine locally though.

Comment: So this is probably a problem of permissions in the tmp folder.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Could you please provide more information? I'm facing the same trouble than the OP and can not use any `fileInput()`. The owner of my `tmp` folder in the server is `root root`, permissions are set to `drwxrwxrwt`.